# Is my brother's phone unfixable?

Tags: htc-one-m8

[image: Brother's Phone's Screen]

This is the screen my brother's phone stays at, no matter what action is done, after his phone died and he tried to plug it in. I've seen similar images but most ways to fix it seem to be "flash a new rom" and even then, the images that were posted in that case didn't have those invalid_ver_info notices.

Is my brother's phone dead or can it be fixed, preferably without flashing the rom and possibly doing more harm than good.

Comment: first of all, relax. You just need right hands with right tool. But, only flashing know-how will not help much. Need deeped expertise.

Answer (score 0):

The same thing happened to a friend of mine and according to him, the following solution worked:

1. Use the volume buttons to turn the phone off
2. Switch it on using the power button
3. If this screen appears again, reboot into fastboot
4. reset the phone via a windows computer

> ```
> fastboot devices
> fastboot erase userdata
> fastboot erase cache
> fastboot reboot
> ```

5. If nothing works, play around with the phone and learn something new!!

Comment: Doesn't this require an unlocked bootloader?

Comment: I was assuming that yours has an unlocked bootloader... :/

Comment: Assuming without mentioning creates misunderstanding and a frustrated user might even downvote your answer for this deliberate mistake. Please avoid this in here and in any answer in future, and make an [edit](http://android.stackexchange.com/posts/110116/edit).